# Button doesn't centerized in Grid container

Tags: html, css, material-ui

I want to centerize the button in `Grid` layout `Material-UI`

```
<Grid container style={{backgroundColor:'green'}} alignItems="center" justify="center" >
    <Grid alignItems="center" justify="center" item xs={12} 
    style={{margin:'auto',width:"100%",backgroundColor:'white'}}>
        <Button variant="contained" style={{margin:'auto'}}>
          Next
        </Button>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

However button shown at the left.

How can I centerize??

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I have simplified your example a bit. Using `xs={12}` was creating column width for the inner `Grid`. As it is using grid, you only need the `alignItems="center"` and `justify="center"` for center alignment on both axis.

```
<Grid container style={{ backgroundColor: "green" }} alignItems="center" justify="center" direction="row">
     <Grid item>
         <Button variant="contained" style={{ margin: "auto" }}>
            Next
         </Button>
     </Grid>
</Grid>
```